# Take advantage of multiple cores executing SQL statements

Tags: sql, insert, parallel-processing

I have a small application that reads XML files and inserts the information on a SQL DB.

There are ~ 300 000 files to import, each one with ~ 1000 records.

I started the application on 20% of the files and it has been running for 18 hours now, I hope I can improve this time for the rest of the files.

I'm not using a multi-thread approach, but since the computer I'm running the process on has 4 cores I was thinking on doing it to get some improvement on the performance (although I guess the main problem is the I/O and not only the processing).

I was thinking on using the BeginExecutingNonQuery() method on the SqlCommand object I create for each insertion, but I don't know if I should limit the max amount of simultaneous threads (nor I know how to do it).

What's your advice to get the best CPU utilization?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are reading those files on the same machine that runs the database. Although I don't know much about your machine, I bet that your bottleneck is disk IO. This doesn't sound terribly computation intensive to me.

Comment: I know the process isn't computation-intensive, but I'm guessing if I do 4 simultaneous inserts, SQL will take advantage of the multiple cores and do it in a more efficient way.

And yes, the IO is intensive, but at least I want to keep SQL as busy as I can.

Comment: Then make sure you're reading the files from another physical drive then the one holding the db.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

> Imports a data file into a database table or view in a user-specified format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)? Basically, you load your data into a DataTable instance, then use the SqlBulkCopy class to load it to SQL Server. Should offer a HUGE performance increase without as much change to your current process as using bcp or another utility.

Comment: The thing is, I have to do some small processing to the information before inserting it, basically the files contain information that goes in 4 different tables, but I'll take a look, it might be useful.

Thanks

Comment: It should help even in that case - perhaps you'd need 4 DataTables to hold the results of your processing, but in any case you should improve your performance.